# Check if Column is Vector Type

Tags: pyspark

I am trying to determine if a column is a vector type, but am running into issues.

After I run a model and create a dataframe called predictions, there is a field called probability.

When I run this code to see the datatype if shows a vector.

```
predictions.schema['probability'].dataType
Out[128]: VectorUDT
```

Then when I run this I get a false returned

```
predictions.schema["probability"].dataType == 'VectorUDT'
Out[129]: False
```

So I tried this

```
dict(predictions.dtypes)['probability'] == 'vector'
Out[130]: True
```

However, when I try to use that in my dataframe I get an error stating TypeError: unhashable type: 'Column'

```
.withColumn('test',   when(dict(predictions.dtypes)['probability'] == 'vector',1)
                           .otherwise(0)) \
```

Comment: Are you trying to extract probability values from predictions?

Comment: Sort of. I am able to just do an extract without issue, but I am building a generic function. Sometimes the column will be the probability field where I extract the values. Other times it will be just a float column. I am wanting check if the input column is of the vector type to do the extraction otherwise leave the column alone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`predictions.schema['probability']` returns a [StructField](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.types.StructField.html) and `StructField.dataType` returns a [DataType](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.types.DataType.html). So

```python
predictions.schema["probability"].dataType == 'VectorUDT'
```

compares a `DataType` with a string and this always `false`.

One way to check for a vector column is to check the type of the `dataType` using [isinstance](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance):

```python
from pyspark.ml.linalg import VectorUDT
isinstance(predictions.schema["probability"].dataType, VectorUDT) #True
```

Another way to check the column type is to use [DataType.simpleString](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.types.DataType.html#pyspark.sql.types.DataType.simpleString) or [DataType.typeName](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.types.DataType.html#pyspark.sql.types.DataType.typeName). Both return the [same string](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/types.html#DataType.simpleString), `vector` for `VectorUDT` fields:

```python
predictions.schema['probability'].dataType.simpleString() == 'vector' #True
```